# Binary tree Delete by merge recursive implementation

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have implemented the iterative version of delete by merge but I'm struggling to implemented recursively.

This is my iterative version:

```
public void deleteByMerging(T el) {
    BSTNode<T> tmp, node, p = root, prev = null;
    while (p != null && !p.el.equals(el)) {  
         prev = p;                           
         if (el.compareTo(p.el) < 0)
              p = p.right;
         else p = p.left;
    }
    node = p;
    if (p != null && p.el.equals(el)) {
         if (node.right == null) 
              node = node.left;  
         else if (node.left == null) 
              node = node.right; 
         else {                  
              tmp = node.left;   
              while (tmp.right != null) 
                  tmp = tmp.right;      
              tmp.right =        
                  node.right;    

              node = node.left;  
         }
         if (p == root)
              root = node;
         else if (prev.left == p)
              prev.left = node;
         else prev.right = node; // 5.
    }
    else if (root != null)
         System.out.println("el " + el + " is not in the tree");
    else System.out.println("the tree is empty");
}
```

Now I need to implement the recursive function in this way:

```
public void delete(T info) {
    root = delete(root, info);
}

public TreeNode<T> delete(TreeNode<T> node, T info) 
    {

    }
```

Im very new with recursion and I have no idea of where to start.

Answer (score 0):

(By "your" iterative version, you of course mean Adam Drozdek's.)

This should work:

```
public void delete(T info) {
    root = delete (root.info);
}

public TreeNode<T> delete(TreeNode<T> node, T info) {

    // if this node is null, we have reached the end of the tree
    // so the node is not in the tree.
    if (node == null) {
        return node; // or handle as required

    // if this is not the node to delete;
    // recursively call this on the node's correct child
    else if (info.compareTo(node.info) <0) {
        node.left = delete(node.left, info);
        return node;
    } else {
        node.right = delete(node.right, info);
        return node;
    }

    // if this is the node to delete:
    else if (node.info.equals(info)) {
        // to delete it, we must return a sub-tree without it.

        if (node.left == null) 
            // this node is a leaf node, or
            // node.right contains only child.
            // either way, return node.right
            return node.right;

        if (node.right == null) 
            // node.left contains only child
            return node.left;

        // else node has 2 children, so delete by merging:
        // first, find its direct predecessor:
        TreeNode<T> tmp = node.left;
        while (tmp.right != null)
            tmp = tmp.right;
        // then append the node's right sub-tree
        // to its direct predecessor:
        tmp.right = node.right;
        // lastly, replace the node by its left sub-tree:
        return node.left;
    }
}
```

First we check if `node` is null. If it is, that means the element we want to delete is not in the tree, because we have traversed until we used up all the nodes where it could have been.

Next, we check if the element is larger than or greater than the element in the current node. If it is, we need to keep on traversing the tree, going left or right depending on how the elements compare. Note that, in the recursive step, we assign the result of a delete operation to one of `node`'s children. We have taken this cue from the first function, where `root` is assigned the result of a delete operation on `root`. This will recursively traverse the tree until `node` refers to the node that you want to delete. We also return `node` here, so that if no changes have occurred, the call to `node.right = delete(node.right, info)`, for example, will not change the current node.

When we have found the node, 4 scenarios are possible: the node can be a leaf node (having no children), or it can have 1 left or 1 right child, or it can have 2 children. The first 3 scenarios are covered by the lines

```
if (node.left == null)
    return node.right;
if (node.right == null)
    return node.left;
```

Note that if `node` has no children, the first `if` check will be true, so `node`'s right child (which is null) will be returned, deleting the node.

Why does returning null delete the node? Because, in the traversal step discussed above, we assign the result of a delete operation to `node`'s child. Note that `node` in the previous recursive step is the parent of `node` in this step, because delete was called recursively on that node's child. So returning null here will cause the previous call to assign null to the parent's child, deleting the child. Basically, any time we return anything other than `node`, we are replacing the current node with whatever we return in the tree.

In the fourth case, we need a simple delete by merging. You can do that by appending `node`'s right sub-tree to the rightmost node in its left sub-tree. First, we find the right-most node in the left sub-tree, which is the direct predecessor of `node`:

```
TreeNode<T> tmp = node.left;
while (tmp.right != null)
    tmp = tmp.right;
```

So `tmp` is now `node`'s direct predecessor. Next we latch `node`'s right sub-tree onto `tmp`:

```
tmp.right = node.right;
```

And lastly, to replace `node` by its left sub-tree, we simply return `node.left`, since this will replace `node` with `node.left` as the child of `node`'s parent in the previous recursive call.

If my explanation confuses you, you can try [this one](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/treeprocessing/). This is much easier to explain with pictures on paper, which is why you should ask me in the practical sessions (yes, I set this prac up) rather than on SO :) Hope you figured it out before the deadline!